# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy nuevo en esto, he buscado la solución a este problema en todos los lugares posibles, pero no me ayuda (Es en python 3). Se trata de un programa que busca la manera más rápida de resolver un juego de gato, dependiendo de si ciertas casillas tiene un valor en especifico (1). Se valida si la fila esta completa, y automáticamente da "success" (success finaliza el programa e imprime el resultado). No cumple su objetivo final ya que faltan cosas por programa pero quiero solucionar ese error para avanzar. Agradecería mucho una respuesta. Gracias

Este es el código que trato de ejecutar:

```
import sys

a1 = 0
a2 = 0
a3 = 0
b1 = 0
b2 = 0
b3 = 0
c1 = 0
c2 = 0
c3 = 0

success_a = False
success_b = False
success_c = False
success_1 = False
success_2 = False
success_3 = False
success_x = False
success_y = False

success = False

userinput = str(input("Ingrese los datos: "))


def define():
    if userinput.count("a1x1") == 1:
        a1 = 1

    if userinput.count("a1x0") == 1:
        a1 = 0

    if userinput.count("b1x1") == 1:
        b1 = 1

    if userinput.count("b1x0") == 1:
        b1 = 0

    if userinput.count("c1x1") == 1:
        c1 = 1

    if userinput.count("c1x0") == 1:
        c1 = 0

    if userinput.count("a2x1") == 1:
        a2 = 1

    if userinput.count("a2x0") == 1:
        a2 = 0

    if userinput.count("b2x1") == 1:
        b2 = 1

    if userinput.count("b2x0") == 1:
        b2 = 0

    if userinput.count("c2x1") == 1:
        c2 = 1

    if userinput.count("c2x0") == 1:
        c2 = 0

    if userinput.count("a3x1") == 1:
        a3 = 1

    if userinput.count("a3x0") == 1:
        a3 = 0

    if userinput.count("b3x1") == 1:
        b3 = 1

    if userinput.count("b3x0") == 1:
        b3 = 0

    if userinput.count("c3x1") == 1:
        c3 = 1

    if userinput.count("c3x0") == 1:
        c3 = 0

    print("Base State:")
    print("",a1,"  ",b1,"  ",c1,"\n\n",a2,"  ",b2,"  ",c2,"\n\n",a3,"  ",b3,"  ",c3)
    print("")

    prevalidation()


def prevalidation():
    if a1 == 1 and a2 == 1 and a3 == 1:
        success_a = True
        validation()
    elif b1 == 1 and b2 == 1 and b3 == 1:
        success_b = True
        validation()

    if c1 == 1 and c2 == 1 and c3 == 1:
        success_c = True
        validation()
    elif a1 == 1 and b1 == 1 and c1 == 1:
        success_1 = True
        validation()

    if a2 == 1 and b2 == 1 and c2 == 1:
        success_2 = True
        validation()
    elif a3 == 1 and b3 == 1 and c3 == 1:
        success_3 = True
        validation()

    if a1 == 1 and b2 == 1 and c3 == 1:
        success_x = True
        validation()
    elif a3 == 1 and b2 == 1 and c1 == 1:
        success_y = True
        validation()

    first_mov()


def first_mov():
    if a1 == 1 and a2 == 0 and a3 == 0:
        a3 = 0
    elif a1 == 0 and a2 == 0 and a3 == 1:
        a1 = 1
    else:
        a2 = 0

    if b1 == 1 and b2 == 0 and b3 == 0:
        b3 = 0
    elif b1 == 0 and b2 == 0 and b3 == 1:
        b1 = 1
    else:
        b2 = 0

    if c1 == 1 and c2 == 0 and c3 == 0:
        c3 = 0
    elif c1 == 0 and c2 == 0 and c3 == 1:
        c1 = 1
    else:
        c2 = 0

    if a1 == 1 and b1 == 0 and c1 == 0:
        c1 = 1
    elif a1 == 0 and b1 == 0 and c1 == 1:
        a1 = 1
    else:
        b1 = 1

    if a2 == 1 and b2 == 0 and c2 == 0:
        c2 = 1
    elif a2 == 0 and b2 == 0 and c2 == 1:
        a2 = 1
    else:
        b2 = 1

    if a3 == 1 and b3 == 0 and c3 == 0:
        c3 = 1
    elif a3 == 0 and b3 == 0 and c3 == 1:
        a3 = 1
    else:
        b3 = 1

    if a1 == 1 and b2 == 0 and c3 == 0:
        c3 = 0
    elif a1 == 0 and b2 == 0 and c3 == 1:
        a1 = 0

    if a3 == 1 and b2 == 0 and c1 == 0:
        c1 = 0
    elif a3 == 0 and b2 == 0 and c1 == 1:
        a3 = 0
    else:
        b2 = 1

    if success == False:
        second_mov()

    validation()


def second_mov():
    if a1 == 1 and a2 == 1:
        a3 = 1
        success_a = True
    elif a1 == 1 and a3 == 1:
        a2 = 1
        success_a = True

    if a2 == 1 and a3 == 1:
        a1 = 1
        success_a = True

    if b1 == 1 and b2 == 1:
        b3 = 1
        success_b = True
    elif b1 == 1 and b3 == 1:
        b2 = 1
        success_b = True

    if b2 == 1 and b3 == 1:
        b1 = 1
        success_b = True

    if c1 == 1 and c2 == 1:
        c3 = 1
        success_c = True
    elif c1 == 1 and c3 == 1:
        c2 = 1
        success_c = True

    if c2 == 1 and c3 == 1:
        c1 = 1
        success_c = True

    if a1 == 1 and b1 == 1:
        c1 = 1
        success_1 = True
    elif a1 == 1 and c1 == 1:
        b1 = 1
        success_1 = True

    if b1 == 1 and c1 == 1:
        a1 = 1
        success_1 = True

    if a2 == 1 and b2 == 1:
        c2 = 1
        success_2 = True
    elif a2 == 1 and c2 == 1:
        b2 = 1
        success_2 = True

    if b2 == 1 and c2 == 1:
        a2 = 1
        success_2 = True

    if a3 == 1 and b3 == 1:
        c3 = 1
        success_3 = True
    elif a3 == 1 and c3 == 1:
        b3 = 1
        success_3 = True

    if b3 == 1 and c3 == 1:
        a3 = 1
        success_3 = True

    if a1 == 1 and b2 == 1:
        c3 = 1
        success_x = True
    elif a1 == 1 and c3 == 1:
        b2 = 1
        success_x = True

    if b2 == 1 and c3 == 1:
        a1 = 1
        success_x = True

    if a3 == 1 and b2 == 1:
        c1 = 1
        success_y = True
    elif a3 == 1 and c1 == 1:
        b2 = 1
        success_y = True

    if b2 == 1 and c1 == 1:
        a3 = 1
        success_y = True

    validation()


def validation():
    if success_a == True or success_b == True or success_c == True or success_1 == True or success_2 == True or success_3 == True or success_x == True or success_y == True:
        success = True

    if success == True:
        print("Mod. State:")
        print("",a1,"  ",b1,"  ",c1,"\n\n",a2,"  ",b2,"  ",c2,"\n\n",a3,"  ",b3,"  ",c3)
        print("")
        print("System: Stopped")
        sys.exit()


define()
```

Este es el error que me tira:

```
File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\gato.py", line 286, in <module>
    define()
File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\gato.py", line 83, in define
    print("",a1,"  ",b1,"  ",c1,"\n\n",a2,"  ",b2,"  ",c2,"\n\n",a3,"  ",b3,"  ",c3)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b1' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analicemos primero que nos dice la excepción:

> variable local 'b1' referenciada antes de asignación

básicamente nos dice que estamos intentando acceder a una variable antes de que se le asignara un objeto.

- En Python cuando creas una variable dentro de una función, dicha variable es de ámbito local a la función por defecto. Es decir, no podrá ser referenciada desde fuera de la función jamás.
- Una función puede referenciar una variable definida a nivel de módulo, global, sin problemas.
- Si una función intenta reasignar un nuevo objeto a una variable definida a nivel global, se genera de forma inmediata una variable local con el mismo nombre, a la cuál se le asigna el objeto, dejando intacta y ensombrecida la global. Es por tanto imposible, por defecto, asignar a una variable global desde una función.

De lo anterior, por lo pronto deducimos que hacer:

```
a1 = 0

def define():
    if userinput.count("a1x1") == 1:
        a1 = 1  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

no va a modificar la variable global `a1`, sino que crea una variable local a `define` a la que se le asigna el valor 1, mientras que la global sigue con 0 y ya no es accesible directamente desde `define` (ensombrecida por la local del mismo nombre).

No obstante, si no se cae en el condicional, no hay resignación, entonces ¿por qué no se referencia la variable global sin más?

Bien, el cuerpo de una función no es evaluado por el intérprete hasta que se ejecuta, (latte binding), pero que no se evaluado, no significa que el intérprete no tenga que crear su objeto función, almacenarlo en memoria y generar el bytecode necesario para cuando sea llamada.

Cuando el intérprete se encuentra con la definición de la función y procede generar el bytecode para ella, el parser se encuentra con que hay una asignación a la variable, en ese mismo instante para él la variable en **toda la función** es ya tratada como una variable local. Un poco de bytecode:

```
import dis


def foo():
    print(m)

print(dis.dis(foo))
```

> ```
> 67           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
>               2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (m)
>               4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
>               6 POP_TOP
>               8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
>              10 RETURN_VALUE
> ```

La linea clave es `2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (m)`, es decir, la variable `m` es cargada desde el espacio de nombres global, como ya explicábamos antes, una función puede referenciar variables globales sin problemas.

En cambio:

```
import dis


def foo():
    print(m)
    m = 0

print(dis.dis(foo))
```

> ```
>  67           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
>               2 LOAD_FAST                0 (m)
>               4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
>               6 POP_TOP
>
>  68           8 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
>              10 STORE_FAST               0 (m)
>              12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
>              14 RETURN_VALUE
> ```

Ahora tenemos que el bytecode para la línea del `print`, nos intenta obtener el valor de la variable `m` mediante `2 LOAD_FAST                0 (m)`, es decir trata de acceder a la variable en el ámbito local de la función, a pesar de que la línea dónde reasignamos va después. Cuando ese bytecode se ejecute, `m` no existe aún en el espacio de nombres local, porque se crea en `10 STORE_FAST               0 (m)`, el resultado, la excepción mostrada.

Por tanto, por ambas razones, debes especificar en la función de forma explícita que tus variables sean tratadas como globales mediante el estamento [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

```
def prevalidation():
    global a1,  a2,  a3,  b1,  b2,  b3
```

ésto permitirá que puedas reasignar y evitar´a el error sobre la variable local no vinculada. Aún cuando solo se pretenda referenciar ("leer") y no reasignar una variable del espacio de nombres global, es buena práctica declararla como global en la función.

La otra opción, es no usar variables globales y hacer que tus funciones reciban las variables como argumento y las retornen al terminar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de verdad me sirvió mucho.